# The total maximum value of the value chosen

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, backtracking

**Problem :**

> Given an array of values [a0,a1,a2,..,an]
>
> - Choose values ​​according to the following rules:
>
>   - Only one value can be taken at a turn.
>   - If this time already chose the k-th value in array, the next turn can only choose value from k + 1 to n-1.
>   - At odd turn ( turn 1, turn 3, ...). Choose any arbitrary values.
>   - At even turn ( turn 2, turn 4, ...). Choose a value with the same value as the previous one.
>
> Find and Print The total maximum value of the values that I can choose

**Example :**

> With a=[2,5,2,6].
>
> - Turn 1, choose 2.
> - Turn 2, choose 2.
> - Turn 3, choose 6.
>
>   - The total maximum values is 10
>
> With a=[6,11,14,0,10,1,11,7,7,11,11,14,14,13,9,0,12,9,11,3].
>
> - The total maximum values is 115

**My code :**

```
def firstpair(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
            if a[i]==a[j]: 
                return [i,j]
    return []
def chooseValues(a):
    s = firstpair(a)
    if len(s)==0: 
        if len(a)==0: return 0
        else: return max(a)
    if s[0]==0: x=0
    else: 
        x = max(a[:s[0]])
    y = a[s[0]]+a[s[1]]+chooseValues(a[s[1]+1:])
    z = chooseValues(a[s[0]+1:])
    return max(x,y,z)
```

***Can I reduce the space complexity for the above solution?***

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it with `n` space and time complexity by going backwards:

```
def max_value(items):
    best = [0 for _ in items] + [0]
    last_seen = {}

    for i in reversed(xrange(len(items))):
        curr = items[i]
        pair = last_seen.get(curr)
        if pair is None:
            choose_this = curr
        else:
            choose_this = curr * 2 + best[pair + 1]
        best[i] = max(choose_this, best[i + 1])
        last_seen[curr] = i
    return best[0]
```

If you wanted to complicate it a bit you could do it with less storage (proportional to unique values) by combining `last_seen` and `best`:

```
def max_value(items):
    best_rest = {None: 0}
    best_max = 0

    for i in reversed(range(len(items))):
        curr = items[i]
        choose_this = curr * 2 + best_rest.get(curr, -curr)
        best_rest[curr] = choose_rest = best_max
        best_max = max(choose_this, choose_rest)
    return best_max
```

In either case:

```
assert max_value([6, 11, 14, 0, 10, 1, 11, 7, 7, 11, 11, 14, 14, 13, 9, 0, 12, 9, 11, 3]) == 115
assert max_value([2, 5, 2, 6]) == 10
```

Comment: Ironically, the more unique values we have (past n/2), the less we need to store.

Comment: What's the benefit of going backwards over forward? It doesn't seem to make a difference if I switch the directions in your code.

Comment: @גלעדברקן it should make a difference, since the problem is not always symmetric, e.g.: `[2,1,2,1] -> 5`, but `[1,2,1,2] -> 4`.

Comment: Yeah, had to wiggle that in my head for a second to see if it was true =)  Regardless it would still honor the original problem by proceeding right to left so that it can be compared with the problem description and typical human attempt, rather than on the potentially equivalent reversed order.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question, though. What's the benefit of going backwards over forward?

Comment: Consider the inverse - why go forward instead of backwards?  For example in a Fibonacci sequence you define F_n in terms of *earlier* results, so it makes sense to go forwards, starting and continuing with known values, if you want to be fast.  In this problem the values depend on *later* results, so starting from the end allows us to collapse state.  Hope this helps

Comment: But my code works bottom-up (left to right) in O(num_unique_values) space and O(n) time. Is there a discrepancy in results? I didn't mean we *should* go forward, just wanted to understand why you said we can do it going backwards, implying it makes a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203694/discussion-between-cireo-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to think about it. Let `f(i, parity)` represent the maximum achieved when the `i`th element is chosen at a step with parity, `parity`. Then:

```
f(i, even) = A[i] + max(f(j, odd)) // requires O(1) storage
  where j < i and A[j] == A[i]

f(i, odd) = A[i] + max(f(j, even)) // requires O(num_unique_Ai) storage
  where j < i
```

```
def f(A):
  max_f_j_even = -float("inf")
  max_f_j_odd = {A[0]: A[0]}
  best = -float("inf")

  for i in range(1, len(A)):
    # Even turn
    new_max_f_j_even = None
    if A[i] in max_f_j_odd:
      new_max_f_j_even = max(max_f_j_even, A[i] + max_f_j_odd[A[i]])

    # Odd turn
    else:
      # A[i] is a first turn
      max_f_j_odd[A[i]] = A[i]

    # A[i] is a later odd turn
    max_f_j_odd[A[i]] = max(max_f_j_odd[A[i]], A[i] + max_f_j_even)

    if new_max_f_j_even != None:
      max_f_j_even = new_max_f_j_even

    best = max(best, max_f_j_even, max_f_j_odd[A[i]])

  return best

A = [2,5,2,6]
print(f(A)) # 10

A = [6,11,14,0,10,1,11,7,7,11,11,14,14,13,9,0,12,9,11,3]
print(f(A)) # 115
```